# Сохранение случайно генерируемых значений в свойстве объекта

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Предложены функции **rand** и **generateId**, генерирующие случайный идентификационный номер. Менять их каким-либо образом - нельзя.

Свойство **id** функции-фабрики **LoyaltyCard** должно получать значение из **generateId**, сохранять его и делать доступным только для чтения. Идея в том, что при обращении к этому свойству из метода по **this.id**, не должна происходить повторная генерация идентификационного номера.

Как можно реализовать это при объявлении свойства?

```
//Неизменяемые функции:
function rand(min, max) {
  return Math.ceil((max - min + 1) * Math.random()) + min - 1;
}

function generateId() {
  return Array(4).fill(1).map(value => rand(1000, 9999)).join('-');
}

//Фабрика объектов:
let LoyaltyCard = function(name, sum) {
  this.owner = name;
  this.id = generateId(); //так свойство генерирует новый ID при каждом обращении к нему
  this.balance = sum;
  this.discount = 0;
  this.orders = Array.of(sum);
}


LoyaltyCard.prototype.show = function() {
  console.log(`Карта ${this.id}:\nВладелец: ${this.owner}\nБаланс: 
${this.balance} Q\nТекущая скидка: ${this.discount} %\nЗаказы:\n  #1 на 
сумму ${this.orders[0]} Q\n  #2 на сумму ${this.orders[1]} Q`);
}
```

Comment: Не очень понятно. Что значит **Идея в том, что при обращении к этому свойству из метода по this.id**. Какой метод вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Добавил в код, так должно быть понятнее.

Comment: _//так свойство генерирует новый ID при каждом обращении к нему_ - функция возвращает строку которая записывается в поле `id`, следовательно при попытке прочитать `id` из объекта ничего заново генерироваться не будет

Comment: @Grundy правильно говорит.

Comment: При каждом вызове значение будет новым.

    const card = new LoyaltyCard('Иванов Иван', 6300);

    console.log(card);

Comment: @OlegBarbasov, и это логично, у тебя же новый объект каждый раз, соответственно и id у него новый.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я вавс правильно понял:

```js
//Неизменяемые функции:
function rand(min, max) {
  return Math.ceil((max - min + 1) * Math.random()) + min - 1;
}

function generateId() {
  return Array(4).fill(1).map(value => rand(1000, 9999)).join('-');
}

const LoyaltyCard = function(name, sum) {
  // Значение хранится в св-ве функции.
  if(LoyaltyCard.commonId_ === undefined) {
    LoyaltyCard.commonId_ = generateId();
  }

  this.owner = name;
  this.id = LoyaltyCard.commonId_; // Теперь генерируется только при самом первом вызове.
  this.balance = sum;
  this.discount = 0;
  this.orders = Array.of(sum);
}

const a = new LoyaltyCard('a', 124);
const b = new LoyaltyCard('b', 124);
const c = new LoyaltyCard('c', 124);

console.log(a.id, b.id, c.id);
```

Comment: а можно было просто вынести вызов функции `generateId` за конструктор и один раз вызвать, а результат уже присваивать, тогда и условие не нужно

Comment: ну можно и так)

Comment: Не похоже, что работает. Код возвращает новые значения при каждом выполнении.

https://repl.it/@Heithwald/SteepMajesticEngineering

Comment: @OlegBarbasov вы запустили мой код? Он выводит одно и то же значение

Comment: @OlegBarbasov каждый раз когда вы нажимаете `Run`, вы, можно сказать, перезагружаете браузер, поэтому значения различаются. На странице одной у всех экземпляров будет одинаковый `id`. Посмотрите, 3 одинаковых числа

Comment: @ThisMan спасибо, понял разницу. 

то же самое получается, если вне конструктора объявить пустой массив:

let idArr = [];

а в конструкторе реализовать следующим образом:

idArr.push(generateId());
  let idVal = idArr[0];
  
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'id', {
      value: idVal
  });

Добавил в repl.

Comment: @OlegBarbasov зачем массив, если вы только первый элемент берете? Почему через `defineProperty`?

Comment: Можно и через переменную.

А defineProperty, т.к. есть задача сделать свойство только для чтения.